# sapply in r with user defined function

Tags: r, sapply

My code is as follows:

```
data("USArrests")

AssignLevel <- function(p,quartiles)
{
  if (p < quartiles[1])
    rlevel <-"LOW"
  else if (p < quartiles[2])
    rlevel <-"MODERATE"
  else if (p < quartiles[3])
    rlevel <-"HIGH"
  else level <-"VERY HIGH"
  return (rlevel)
}
k<-USArrests$UrbanPop
k

q<- quantile(USArrests$UrbanPop, c(.25,.5,.75))

newCol <- sapply(USArrests$UrbanPop,AssignLevel(k,q))
```

I'm trying to change the value of every state's urban pop value into one of the corresponding quartiles. It works when I run `AssignLevel(k,q)` but not when I run in in sapply.

Comment: Seems like you should just be using `cut` instead, quite frankly.

Comment: aye: `cut(USArrests$UrbanPop, breaks=c(min(USArrests$UrbanPop), q, max(USArrests$UrbanPop)), labels=c("LOW", "MODERATE", "HIGH", "VERY HIGH"), include.lowest=TRUE)` is much cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that the `cut` solution is better. For fun, here is how to resolve your current issue:

```
data("USArrests")

AssignLevel <- function(p,quartiles) {
  if (p < quartiles[[1]]){
    rlevel <- "LOW"
  } else if(p < quartiles[[2]]) {
    rlevel <- "MODERATE"
  } else if(p < quartiles[[3]]) {
    rlevel <- "HIGH"
  } else {
    rlevel <- "VERY HIGH"
  }
  return (rlevel)
}
k <- USArrests$UrbanPop

q <- quantile(k, c(.25,.5,.75))


newCol <- sapply(k,AssignLevel,q)
```